# angularjs form issues

Tags: angularjs

I'm having issues with trying to get a form to work with angularjs. Here is the error

`{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x9bd4f8c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x9dc06ec>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}`

In case this may help, this is the jsfiddle I am using:

http://jsfiddle.net/YYrZ3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your fiddle:

1. You need to load AngularJS framework (change from "No-library" to "AngularJS 1.0.3")
2. Set the load method to "no-wrap (head)"
3. Define the app (`<body ng-app="customerApp">`) on the info panel
4. Fix your `func` service (check the fiddle below). You're definning functions on the module and not on the service. Also check AngularJS [service documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services).
5. Remove the `method="post"` from your HTML

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/YYrZ3/1/

Comment: Load AngularJS into the fiddle?

Comment: It is saying this now:   `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

Comment: Change the "Body Tag" on the info panel to `<body ng-app="customerApp">` (step 3)